# Conditional data validation in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently creating a form in Google Sheet to manage locker assignments for staff.
The idea is to be able to select a locker via a drop down menu depending on the locker room chosen (via another drop down menu). I have a database with a column for the locker room, another for the locker and finally a last one to indicate the name of the person who owns the locker.

So for the first drop-down menu (the locker room choice) I created a data validation in which I selected the whole of my locker room column. For the second drop-down menu, I added a column in my database in which all the results will be displayed according to the selected locker room.

Here is the code I entered:
=FILTER(B2:B16;A2:A16=Form!B5)

And here is the link to my file:
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fml5ObS7eicoKD11Tcm5AcMu6qEn9fk8E3Y6nxqamf8/edit?usp=sharing)

It works, however I would like to be able to display only the lockers that are available (and therefore where there is no name indicated on the locker line in question).

I tried =SI(C2:C16!="";B2:B16;"") but it does not work.
I have searched but I can't find any sites where this is mentioned.

Does anyone have an idea please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. 
Here is the formula for those who are interested: =FILTER(B2:B16;(A2:A16=Form!B5)*(C2:C16=""))
However, I would like to deepen this formula by displaying in priority the racks ending with _A (I updated the file I shared above, tabs 3 and 4).
Thanks in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use this formula to sort the result range from A to B:

```
=index(sort({FILTER(B2:B21;(A2:A21=Form!B5)*(C2:C21=""))\arrayformula(right(FILTER(B2:B21;(A2:A21=Form!B5)*(C2:C21=""));2))};2;TRUE);0;1)
```

Basically, another column was built from the result range that has the first character trimmed out:

```
arrayformula(right(FILTER(B2:B21;(A2:A21=Form!B5)*(C2:C21=""));2))
```

This was merged with the original result range, then sorted. Finally INDEX was used to get the first column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query({A2:C21\arrayformula(split(B2:B21;"_"))};"select Col2 where Col1='"&Form!B5&"' and Col3 is not null order by Col5";0)
```

If Form!B5 = B [image]